# $cookieStore - Unable to retrieve cookie values on different page

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am using angularjs $cookieStore to manipulate cookies on my website. I am putting userId and userName in the cookie as soon as the user logs in successfully. This happens on my website's home page. I can see the cookie values are set correctly (via inspect element on chrome) and also the path is set to '/'. Once the user logs in successfully he/she is directed to another page say page B. I then try to access the cookie values from page B and I am unable to retrieve them.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Are you changing domains? If so, your cookie will be unavailable.

Comment: No, I am not changing domain. It's just another page in the same domain which is trying to read the values from the cookie.

Comment: any updates on this ?